# Include checkstyle rule name in exception message in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I'm looking for an elegant way of suppressing checkstyle warnings in source code in IntelliJ.

If necessary I want to use annotations from [SuppressWarningsFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressWarningsFilter), e. g. `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:AbbreviationAsWordInName")`. To use this I need of course the name of the rule ("AbbreviationAsWordInName") and I cant find it in IntelliJ. It's written to output of Maven's `checkstyle` goal but it's exhausting to search for rule name at another location.

Is there a way to integrate Checkstyle rule name in IntelliJ's warning message?

Comment: I don't think so ... you might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues) with a feature request.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/371).